# how to create 5 <p>'s with 5 text nodess inside using plain JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have ajax api response with `array [1]` which contains 5 text `nodes [i]`. 
I want to put each text node in separate `<p>` instead of all in one `<p>` as I did in my code, so I can make each of them links and put some text as description.

This is the markup,

```
<div class="container"></container>
```

And my code:

```
var p = document.createElement('P');
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
container.appendChild(p);

for(var i=0;i<parsed_json[1].length;i++){
    p.innerHTML += parsed_json[1][i];
}
```

Comment: Please use the preview that the site made you scroll past before you could use the Post Your Question button. It's there, and in front of the button, for a *reason*.

Comment: So, you know how to create a `p` element, and you know you want five of them. The code creates one of them. What's the question exactly? Create five of them instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
for(var i=0;i<parsed_json[1].length;i++){
 var p = document.createElement('P');
 var textnode = document.createTextNode(parsed_json[1][i]);
 p.appendChild(textnode);
 container.appendChild(p);
}
```